# Paypal integration with payment hold option

Tags: paypal

I have a requirement. I have a website where student and teacher can login. There is a chat session between teacher and student for related cource. Now my requirement is Once any course completed it will directly pay the amount to the admin Paypal account , and if there is no dispute flagged from the user / student or admin end within 36 hours, then it will automatically payed to that teachers account.

Is this possible. How can I do this? Is this paypal pro which helps me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try processing transactions as an Order or Authorization. The money is reserved on the buyers funding source for three days. After the 36 hour period you can submit the capture API call to complete the payment.

If you're just going to use Authorization the teacher can complete the transaction themselves through their account. It may be safer to process Orders. It will take an extra step but the teacher can't claim the money manually.

When a transaction is processed as an Order you have to first submit a DoAuthorization API call and then later the DoCapture API call to complete. That is the only way to actually receive the money through an Order.