# On Hold PayPal payments & Transfer to another PayPal account via API

Tags: php, paypal

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893242/paypal-integration-with-payment-hold-option), I know there is a "Hold" feature in PayPal. The scenario I would like to build is:

User can choose from one of the plans below:

```
Plan A --> Pay $5 ~ $500 to PayPal account A
Plan B --> Pay $10 ~ $500 to PayPal account B
Plan C --> Pay $5 ~ $500 to PayPal account A & $10 ~ $500 to PayPal account B
```

Requirements:

- Payments are on hold until a specific day in future has arrived, say January 1, 2016
- Record the amount of each option hold successfully

However, PayPal account A and B are not under my control. I have a PayPal account C which has applied for [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/). Is it possible to use the API to achieve the above?

I can only think of two ways:

**Method 1**

Give up API, add "Donate button" for each Plan. (but how can I record the total amount of payment?)

**Method 2**

All plans pay to account C first, then on specific day, release the payment to account A & B. Problem is, people won't trust account C unless it's a trustworthy account.

Note: I'm using PayPal API with PHP.

---

[Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com) uses similar mechanism, via Amazon Payments. How can they do it ? The funds gathered are transferred to Kickstarter first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure if the REST API will handle that sort of thing yet, but I know [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) will.  Check out [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) specifically.

Comment: Adaptive payments are promising (it's strange to have no REST API version)

Comment: REST may do it, I'm just not as familiar with it.  It looks like the CreatePayment stuff in REST allows you to include multiple transactions, so I'd imagine it's very similar.

Comment: in other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments), PayPal guy said it is not implemented yet.

Comment: Ah, well that answers that.